# No "Done" at end of program in ti basic

Tags: ti-basic

Basically, I just want TI basic to not show the "Done" line at the end of the program. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by writing a blank value at the end of the program:

```
:ClrHome:"
```

More details: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/cleanup